# QAbstractTableModel don't work (Qt6.5.2 / Py 3.11 / )

Tags: python, tableview, qt6, qabstracttablemodel, qsqlquerymodel

I use this code and it works fine:

```
    ....
    self.query_model = QSqlQueryModel()
    view = QTableView()
    view.setModel(self.query_model)
```

... but I would like to use a QAbstractTableModel because then I have more influence on the design of the table. Unfortunately my code doesn't work.

​
My changed code:

```
        self.query_model = QSqlQueryModel()       
        tab_model = MyTableModel(self.query_model)
        view = QTableView()
        view.setModel(tab_model)
```

and:

```
class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, model):
        super().__init__(model)
        self._model_sql = model
        self._headers = headers 

    def rowCount(self, index=None):
        return self._model_sql.rowCount()

    def columnCount(self, index=None):
        return self._model_sql.columnCount()

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole and orientation == Qt.ItemDataRole.Horizontal:
            if section == 0:
                return "KDNr."

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            print("index: " + str(index))
            return None
        elif role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            column = index.column()
            if column == 0:
                return self._model_sql.record(index.row()).value(column)
            elif column == 1:
                value = self._model_sql.record(index.row()).value(column)
                return f"RIP {value}"
            else:
                return None
        return None
```

The table does not appear

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do but I'm guessing what you're actually looking for is a [proxy model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qidentityproxymodel.html).

Comment: Thank you for your message. I want to associate a SQLQueryQuery with a QAbstractTableModel. The QAbstractTableModel is then represented on the screen by a QTableView object. If I link my QSqlQUeryModel directly to a QTableView I get the desired output. There seems to be a bug in the QAbstractTableModel integration, but I don't recognize it.

Comment: Sorry but your last comment makes no sense to me at all.  What's a `SQLQueryQuery`?  Note that `QSqlQueryModel` *is* a `QAbstractTableModel` in that it inherits `QAbstractTableModel`.  If you want to extend its functionality then either derive your own class from `QSqlQueryModel` or, as mentioned previously, use a proxy model.

Comment: No, I have to apologize. I wrote something stupid with "SQL Query Query". It seems like I didn't understand something. Sorry, I've only been using Qt for a short time. I'll describe my project: I'm making a database query with QSqlQueryModel. Now I want to display the result of this query on the screen.

Comment: A "QTableView" is not sufficient because, for example, I want to output checkboxes instead of 1 or 0 or negative numbers in red. My understanding of the documentation is that this is best solved via a "QAbstractTabelModel". So I'm trying to convert my QSqlQueryModel into a QAbstractTableModel and then show it on the screen with a QTableView. I hope this Text is understandable. Thank you in advance for reading.

Comment: I found the mistake. This code needs to be exchanged for it to work:. if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole and orientation == Qt.Orientation.Horizontal: Now I can incorporate my color and display wishes into the code.
Thank you for your support !! i